# Para que serve a função addcslashes em php?

Tags: php

Para que serve a função addcslashes? eu vi no manual do PHP mas não entendi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o manual:

> Retorna uma string com barras invertidas antes dos caracteres que
>   estão listados no parâmetro charlist.

Exemplo:

```
php > echo addcslashes("Ola! Meu nome é Homer. Tudo bem?", "!.?");
Ola\! Meu nome é Homer\. Tudo bem\?
```

Normalmente usa-se o caracter de escape () quando você deseja alterar o sentido original do caracter.

Por exemplo, se quiser imprimir o "\n". O caracter \ tem um sentido especial (escapar o caracter seguinte). No caso, ele transforma a sequencia em uma mudanca de linha. Caso seja executado:

```
echo "\n";
```

Sera impressa uma mudança de linha. Caso você desejar imprimir (literalmente) \n, você precisa usar \n. Será interpretado da seguinte forma:

: Olha, o proximo caracter não tem o sentido usual.

: Meu sentido usual é escapar o proximo caracter, mas o caracter anterior alterou meu sentido. Entao serei interpretado como apenas uma barra.

n: sou apenas um n.

E, como resultado, será impresso "\n".

**Voltando ao addcslashes**

Voce especifica a string e quais caracteres deseja inserir a \ na frente, de modo a alterar seu sentido usual. Normalmente é usado para escapar strings para impressao ou processamento.

Comment: Entendi, mas qual é a lógica de se usar essa função? ou seja em quais as ocasiões ela é utilizada, sou estudante em PHP e vejo muito nos códigos em PHP que estou estudando.